# RaspberryPi OpenCV ImportError undefined symbol

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I installed opencv-2.4.9 on my raspberry pi.When i try to run facedetect.py sample file,i am getting that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "facedetect.py", line 10,in <module>

  import cv2.cv as cv

ImportError: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4: undefined symbol:
```

How can i solve this ? I am getting the same error when compiling cpp or any other example file. Qt's version is 4.

Comment: Can you give more of the traceback? This looks incomplete as it doesn't show which symbol is actually undefined.

It would also help if you mention the version of Qt installed.

Comment: [link](http://i63.tinypic.com/ravuwy.png) here is screen shot of the error. There is no more information than i said in question. My qt's version is 4. @ffledgling

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're either missing a shared library, or there's a version mismatch between the versions of OpenCV and Qt installed.

You'll need to check what the missing/undefined symbol is, which version of libQtGui.so provides it and then check if you have the correct version installed.

Comment: how can i check it ?

Comment: Your error doesn't actually show what symbol is missing or undefined so it's a little hard to check. Are you running this over SSH or in a an interactive session?

Comment: i am running over SSH and remote deskop connection. The error is same on both of them.